# Limit 2nd date selection to only after the first one

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, datepicker

I have 2 html form with datetime pickers. 
I want to limit the user on the 2nd selection to only allow them to select the date only after the first date selection date.

Just don't know how. Thank you.

p.s. I noticed others similar question included jquery but since it's being frowned upon is there a way to do it with vanilla js?

html:

```
<div>
<label> Travel date: </label>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="DateTime">
<label> Return date: </label>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="ReturnDateTime">
</div>
```

Comment: who frowned upon jQuery?

Comment: The internet people. They say it's not necessary anymore since javascript improve a lot and using jquery is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

by default make first datepicker disabled,when user select first date ,make second date picker enabled,

```
  //your javascript should be like 
  function handleFirstDateSelect(){
    let datepicker2=document.getElementById('date2')
          datepicker2.disabled=false;
//rest of your code
  }
```

your html like

```
 <div>
  <label> Travel date: </label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="DateTime" onChange='handleFirstDateSelect()'>

 <label> Return date: </label>
 <input type="datetime-local" name="ReturnDateTime" disabled>
</div>
```